# Automapper autoregister for ClassOfSubclass (Generics with "Of")

Tags: c#, generics, asmx, automapper

ASMX unfortunately generates absurd composite classes from Generics, like:

```
// "DTOs"
public class RootClass<T> {
   ...
}
public class SubClass { ... }

// method
public RootClass<SubClass> SomeMethod()...
```

would result in the autogenerated class `RootClassOfSubClass`.

I'm creating proxy wrappers back to the original types (don't ask), and Automapper seemed ideal to convert `RootClassOfSubClass` back to `RootClass<SubClass>`.

However, I'm feeling lazy and would NOT like to explicitly write out all of the possible mappings.  I might be okay with doing something like:

1. Scan assembly for types containing "Of"
2. Split out the name and "recombine" it into something `Type.GetType(string)` understands
3. `Mapper.CreateMap(originalType, newTypeFromStep2)`

but I run into the problem where I need to know the assembly for each of the component types, which may be from other assemblies.

I'm looking for suggestions:

1. Does AutoMapper already do this more elegantly?  I couldn't find anything about it.
2. Best way to create type from a name

Sorta similar to [Automapper, generics, dto funtimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755864/automapper-generics-dto-funtimes)?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I am painfully aware of its obsolescence, but I'm supporting a legacy app, sooo.....

Comment: @JohnSaunders The fact that it's an ASMX webservice is only relevant to help people visualize the scenario, and really has no bearing on my question -- the key is that I want to use AutoMap to _automatically_ convert one type to another similarly named, composite type.

Comment: I suggest that, if a detail is not relevant, then the detail should be omitted.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I've found that including background/scenario details is helpful when searching for answers, especially when in a similar situation and things may be phrased differently.  So while it's not relevant to _answering_ the question, it's relevant to _finding_ it.

Comment: I disagree. It wouldn't help anyone find the question if they were searching for the same problem, but happened to be using WCF or Web API.